# Drawing a shape with dimensions in millimeters

Tags: flutter, draw, shapes

I have dimensions in millimeters (**mostly rectangles and squares**) and I'm trying to draw them to their size.

Something like so *6.70 x 4.98 x 3.33 mm*.

I really won't be using the depth in the object but just threw it in.

New to drawing shapes with my hands ;)

Comment: So you want these items to render as their non-digital sizes? To convert pixels into mm?

Comment: Or just to keep the aspect ratio and create a relative projection of these shapes?

Answer (score 0):

Screens are typically measured in pixels (android) or points (ios). Both amount to the old standard of 72 pts/in. Though, now we have devices with different pixel ratios. To figure out an exact size would mean you need to determine the current device's screen size and it's pixel ratio. Both can be done with WidgetsBinding.instance.window... Then you just do the math from there to convert those measurements to mm.

However, this seems like an odd requirement so you may just be asking how to draw a square of an exact size. You may want to look into the Canvas/Paint API which can be used in conjunction with a CustomPainter. Another option is a Stack with some Position.fromRect or .fromRelativeRect and draw them using that setup.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want to do. I am going to be rendering these sizes and comparing multiple items so see how they compare to each other. Instead of pulling out a ruler and drawing these and comparing them.

Comment: Then yeah, the route to go about doing this is to grab those specs, do the math for the device running and then draw using what I mentioned above using the conversion ratio of mm-to-pixel you determine prior.